# React HOC returns an anonymous _class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm using MaterialUI, more specifically the `TextField` component which I want to decorate somehow to handle validation state at a component level.

I know about the HOC in react, which is a pattern that seems to be perfect for this. But I have to return an anonymous class and therefore I cannot get the value of the `TextField` component as I should, because the type returned is `_class` instead of `TextField`.

Am I doing something wrong with the HOC pattern, or perhaps this is not the best way to reuse a component without modifying its prototype. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The HOC declaration

```
export default function hocInputValidator( WrappedComponent ){
  return class extends Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }

    handleChange(){
      console.log('Handling from HOC');
    }

    render(){
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
    }
  }
}
```

**The invocation and exporting of the decorated component**

```
export default hocInputValidator(TextField);
```

When I try to access the decorated component via `refs`, the type is `_class` instead of `TextField`.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem with the given solution? Please do let us know. If not we can help you further to figure it out.

Comment: Hello, Ravindra! No, unfortunately no, whether HOC is not the best solution for this or there are some issues with the implementation of components on the Material UI side, the weird thing is that per what I've read HOC is a type of composition, and therefore it must be possible to solve this by implementing it, composition is nothing else than the Liskov Substitution Principle (one of the SOLID principles), so, it makes a lot of sense from a logic perspective (I'm just guessing).

Answer (score 0):

HOCs are used mainly for cross cutting of concerns for an example Login. Many components in your app  may require Login functionality, hence you can wrap them with an HOC dynamically. An HOC will merely wrap whatever the component that is passed into it. In your case I figured out few issues in your code. I have fixed them below.

```
export default function ( WrappedComponent ){
     class HocInputValidator extends Component{
        constructor(props){
          super(props);
        }

        handleChange(){
          console.log('Handling from HOC');
        }

        render(){
          return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
        }
      }
      return HocInputValidator;

}
```

The invocation should be something like this.

```
import inputValidator from './components/input_validator';

inputvalidator(TextField);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HOC returns an anonymous class which is why it's being displayed as `_class`.

To work around this you can [set the HOC's `displayName` to something descriptive](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-wrap-the-display-name-for-easy-debugging) which will override the `_class` display behaviour.

For instance, you can display the HOC as something like `HigherOrderComponent(WrappedComponent)` in the DOM which is more descriptive (and easier to debug). It's a convention followed by other libraries such as `react-redux`.